# How to remote access gcp ports of mongodb on gcp VM?

Tags: mongodb, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, remote-access

I have installed and running mongodb on port 27017 of my VM on gcp. But I am not able to access database from my pc or any external client.

I have set firewall rules to allow ingress traffic with tcp protocol on port 27017(tcp:27017) from all ip ranges(0.0.0.0/0) and have set priority 1000. 
[firewall rules snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgTFZ.png)

Now when i am trying to access the database from external client I am not able to access it. I even tried mongodb compass and used ip address of VM and port 27017 to access the database. But unable to connect and showing(mongodb not running on provided host and port) however I am able to access to database when accessed from that VM itself in which I have installed the mongodb.
Please suggest if I am missing out anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MongoDB doesn’t allow remote connections. So I would suggest you follow [this](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/) tutorial to resolve your issue.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Yes it helped. just changed bind_ip from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Add `--bind_ip_all` to mongodb server start command.

Comment: No it didnt worked. changed bind_ip from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 manually in config file.